# JIRA API returning only 50 issues

Tags: python, jira

I'm using the [JIRA-python library](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) to work with a JIRA tracking system. The command: jira_object.search_issues('project name') is returning only 50 issues. 
There appears no way to change this upper limit in python library specification.
Any pointers will be helpful.
Thanks,
Anjan

Comment: There's a `maxResults` flag: `oh_crap = jira.search_issues('assignee = currentUser() and due < endOfWeek() order by priority desc', maxResults=5)`. Try setting it ti a larger number than 50.

Answer (score 6):

It happens that you can set `maxResults` for your request. The default value is 50.

```
jira_object.search_issues('project name', maxResults=100)
```

#### Reference:

https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/master/jira/client.py#L1706

Answer (score 2):

with maxResults, you can only fetch maximum of 100 issue. So setting maxResults=200 would still yield only 100 issues. I suggest you fetch the issues iteratively.

```
project_name = 'my project'
size = 100
initial = 0
while True:
start = initial * size
issues = self.jira_head.search_issues('project = "{}"'.format(project_name),start,size)

for issue in issues:
     print('description=', issue.fields.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know the amount of results, you can do something like this, I suppose:

```
query = 'project = "myProject"'
pos = 0;
batch = 50;
max = 500;
issues_all = []
while True:
    issues_batch = jira.search_issues(jql_str=query, startAt=pos, maxResults=batch)
    if issues_batch == []:
        break
    else:
        issues_all += issues_batch
    pos += batch
```